# Getting undefined when selecting html element in Javascript

Tags: select, clone

I have a number of tv display clones loaded onto my page. After the clone is made, it will create a new TV object at the end of the loop definition, but for some reason, when it tries to access the index based canvas element from the page, it returns undefined. I tested that when hardcoding cnvs[0] from inside the constructor, it will return the canvas element. Indexing cnvs[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKNkC.png) will return undefined; however, I see the tv has already been cloned before this line is executed. Shouldn't there then be a second canvas element of class ".static" that can be selected? In addition to the code, I attached a screenshot of my debugger screen in Chrome to see what the scope reads following "this.cnv = cnvs[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKNkC.png)", which should dynamically be cnvs[this.index]. Thanks in advance!

```
const container = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
const template = document.getElementsByClassName("tv-set")
const cnvs = $(".static");


/**TBD**/
class TV {
    constructor (id = "tv-0", name = "Blank Slate") {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        console.log("NEW TV CREATED: ", this);
        console.log("ID: ", this.id);
        this.gifArr = gifCarousel_dict[this.name];
        console.log("Media selection for this tv: ", this.gifArr);
        // this.cnv = $(this.id).find('.static')[0];
        // this.cnv = document.querySelector("[data-name=" + CSS.escape(this.id) + "]");
        this.index = getSecondPart(id);
        // this.cnv = $(".static")[this.index + 1];
        this.cnv = cnvs[1];
        console.log(this.cnv);
        this.cnv.setAttribute("c", this.cnv.getContext("2d"));
        this.cnv.setAttribute("cw", this.cnv.offsetWidth);
        this.cnv.setAttribute("ch", this.cnv.offsetHeight);
        this.staticScrn = this.cnv.getAttribute("c").createImageData(this.cnv.setAttribute("ch"), this.cnv.setAttribute("cw"));
        console.log("This canvas element: ", this.cnv);
        //Static display 
        this.isStatic = true;
    }

    showStatic() {
        console.log(`Printing the tv name from the prototype fxn: ${this.name}`);
        // this.isStatic = true;
            c.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

            for (var i = 0; i < staticScrn.data.length; i += 4) {
                let shade = 127 + Math.round(Math.random() * 128);
                staticScrn.data[0 + i] = shade;
                staticScrn.data[1 + i] = shade;
                staticScrn.data[2 + i] = shade;
                staticScrn.data[3 + i] = 255;
            }
            c.putImageData(staticScrn, 0, 0);

            staticTO = setTimeout(runStatic, 1e3 / staticFPS);
        }
}

for (let i = 0; i < phases.length; i++) {
    const clone = template[i].cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute("id", "tv-" + (i + 1))
    console.log("clone id: ", clone.getAttribute("id"))
    clone.setAttribute("data-channel", 0)
    clone.setAttribute("name", phases[i])
    // clone.style.backgroundColor = phases[i].channels[0]
    container.appendChild(clone)
    
    var tvName = 'tvPhase' + clone.getAttribute("name");

    //Instantiate TV object  
    window['tvPhase' + clone.getAttribute("name")] = new TV(clone.getAttribute("id"), clone.getAttribute("name"));
    console.log("New Tv Created: ", tvName)

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I was about to post this question, I caught my bug...but I figured perhaps someone could learn from my stupid mistake! Turns out, it was because of line const cnvs = $(".static"); Setting this constant prior to the cloning operation means it will contain only the first canvas element and cannot be changed even after clones are created since it's a constant (face palm). The solution, of course, is to just define this.cnv = $(".static")[this.index]; directly or set the global cnvs as a var/let cnvs, still wrapping my head around when to use which.